# Functions missing in repl.it Scheme?

Tags: scheme

Using scheme in repl.it, several functions don’t  appear to exist, such as modulo, remainder, inc. Am I missing something? Do I need to import some library or anything? I know there are various permutations of scheme but as far as I can tell these are actual base scheme functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time of writing [repl.it](https://repl.it/languages/scheme) uses [BiwaScheme](https://www.biwascheme.org) v0.6.4 under the hood, which is quite incomplete (the most recent version is v0.7.0, by the way.) It does not fully implement a [Revised Report](https://schemers.org) for the Scheme language, because procedures such as `modulo` or `remainder` are a standard part of the language. According to their implementation [status](https://www.biwascheme.org/doc/conformance.html) page:

> BiwaScheme has most features of [R6RS](http://www.r6rs.org/) Base library. The biggest features not implemented are errors and syntax-rules (you can use define-macro instead).

In particular, the arithmetic section is listed as "not yet" conforming to the standard. There isn't much you can do about it, apart from switching to a standard-conformant interpreter. May I suggest [Racket](https://racket-lang.org)?

Comment: Thanks. I'd been using DrRacket, but it's annoying to use when you're used to modern IDEs like VScode, if only for the keyboard navigation and editing capabilities that are missing from DrRacket.

Comment: @JonathanTuzman but you can use Racket's CLI and invoke it from any text editor you prefer, the best of both worlds ;)

Comment: Or the opposite, I guess? Which is to write in repl (or vscode etc) and paste it into Racket. I mean I assume that's what you meant anyway.

Comment: No, I meant: write code in your favorite editor, and configure it to execute `raco`, Racket's CLI tool, to compile and run in the console. See the [docs](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/other-editors.html).

Comment: I've been looking into that and I'm having trouble figuring out how exactly to do that, which probably sounds dumb. I've found Magic Racket in VS Code which has "run file in terminal" command which puts the output in the terminal. Obviously that's missing all the debugging and other features of drracket.